# Why is dictionary lookup in Python always slower when using user defined objects as keys?

Tags: python, performance, dictionary, hash, lookup

I noticed that when I use user-defined objects (that override the `__hash__` method) as keys of my dicts in Python, lookup time increases by at least a factor 5.

This behaviour is observed even when I use very basic hash methods such as in the following example:

```
class A:
    def __init__(self, a):
        self.a = a
    def __hash__(self):
        return hash(self.a)
    def __eq__(self, other):
        if not isinstance(other, A):
            return NotImplemented
        return (self.a == other.a and self.__class__ == 
                other.__class__)

# get an instance of class A
mya = A(42)
# define dict
d1={mya:[1,2], 'foo':[3,4]}
```

If I time the access through the two different keys I observe a significant difference in performance

```
%timeit d1['foo']
```

results in ~ 100 ns. Whereas

```
%timeit d1[mya]
```

results in ~ 600 ns.

If I remove the overwriting of `__hash__` and `__eq__` methods, performance is at the same level as for a default object

Is there a way to avoid this loss in performance and still implement a customised hash calculation ?

Comment: Not easily. Your `__hash__` and `__eq__` are Python functions, the corresponding methods of builtin types are written in C, therefore faster.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The default CPython `__hash__` implementation for a custom class is written in C and uses the memory address of the object. Therefore, it does not have to access absolutely anthing from the object and can be done very quickly, as it is just a single integer operation in CPU, if even that.

The "very basic" `__hash__` from the example is not as simple as it may seem:

```
def __hash__(self):
    return hash(self.a)
```

This has to read the attribute `a` of `self`, which I'd say in this case will call `object.__getattribute__(self, 'a')`, and that will look for the value of 'a' in `__dict__`. This already involves calculating `hash('a')` and looking it up. Then, the returned value will be passed to `hash`.

---

To answer the additional question:

> Is there a way to implement a faster `__hash__` method that returns
>   predictable values, I mean that are not randomly computed at each run
>   as in the case of the memory address of the object ?

Anything accessing attributes of objects will be slower than the implementation which does not need to access attributes, but you could make attribute access faster by using [`__slots__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#slots), or implementing a highly optimized C extension for the class.

*There is, however, another question: is this really a problem? I cannot really believe that an application is becoming slow because of slow `__hash__`. `__hash__` should still be pretty fast unless the dictionary has trillions of entries, but then, everything else would become slow and ask for bigger changes...*

---

I did some testing and have to make a correction. Using `__slots__` is not going to help in this case at all. My tests actually showed that in CPython 3.7 the above class becomes slightly **slower** when using `__slots__`.

Comment: Is there a way to implement a faster `__hash__` method that returns predictable values, I mean that are not randomly computed at each run as in the case of the memory address of the object ?

Comment: @PaoloGervasoniVila See addition to my answer.

Comment: @PaoloGervasoniVila: Compute the hash during `__init__` and store it as an attribute, so the implementation become `def __hash__(self): return self.precomphash`. Still going to be slower than hashing Python built-ins (and use more memory than before), but that's just how Python works; built-ins (and C extensions) are faster, period.